# Is it possible to debug .NET Class Library Methods as well?

Tags: .net, class, debugging

With .NET Reflector we can see many .NET Class Library method's implementations.

But is it possible to debug them as well? Or if I can put a break point inside them?

Comment: As pointed out you can debug into the .NET framework using Microsofts published symbols...you're unlikely to have debug symbols for other 3rd Party libraries you might use. One piece of advice though, use the .NET framework debugging symbols to work out what you've done wrong...don't use them to identify bugs in the framework because almost without fail it'll be your fault :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with that, but you can with this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to debug .NET framework code.

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://olegsych.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!D6CE2A0548083D95!123.entry) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to follow the instructions in the blog post silky and Frederik have supplied.

For completeness, you can also use an addin for Reflector called [deblector](http://www.codeplex.com/deblector), or wait until [.Net Reflector Pro](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/bart/archive/2009/08/19/74440.aspx) (or [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/clivet/archive/2009/07/20/74071.aspx)) is released, which will let you do exactly what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2005 I had to use the [Mass Downloader](http://www.codeplex.com/NetMassDownloader) to get the code and the symbols. Then configure it as the VS 2008, and load the debugging symbols manually from the file (right click on the call stack).